# ASP.NET Core KestrelServerOptions.ListenAnyIP Method - IPv6 *and* IPv4 binding

Tags: asp.net-core

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.listenanyip?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for the method reads:

> "Listens on all IPs using IPv6 [::], or IPv4 0.0.0.0 if IPv6 is not supported."

Consequently, on a host where IPv6 *is* supported, I would expect a binding only to [::] and *not* to 0.0.0.0. Indeed, a start-up message indicates that to be the case:

> Now listening on: http://[::]

However, on Windows at least, I am seeing a binding to 0.0.0.0 via netstat to which the service responds as it does over v6. I need the service to listen on both v6 and v4, so everything works as I *require* but not as I *expect*!

The underlying logic seems to be [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Servers/Kestrel/Core/src/AnyIPListenOptions.cs) which would suggest a call to `base.BindAsync(context, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)` would need to throw an exception for fallback to `IPAddress.Any` via `EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, IPEndPoint.Port)` which I think will bind only to IPv4 based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.any?view=net-8.0). However, I am seeing binding to both v4 and v6.

If I call `Listen(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort)` in place of the call to `ListenAnyIP` I get a binding only to 0.0.0.0, which makes me suspect the `catch` branch isn't executed.

What am I missing?! I'd like to be confident the behaviour will persist on deployment into other environments.

Comment: A pragmatic answer may be to simply call [UseUrls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.useurls?view=aspnetcore-8.0) passing `http://*:port`. Documentation for the method makes no reference to v4 or v6 binding, and seems to bind to both.